# update the list using onscroll event

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

when I scroll to the bottom of the page, I want the page to load `<li>info</li>`.

```
$window.onscroll = function($event){
                     if($window.pageYOffset > [the parent element height]){
                       //TODO
                     }
                   };
```

So how can I get the parent element height using angular? I try to visit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window to find the related api but this page didn't list the attr of the $window, by the way, how can I get all attrs of $window in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$document.on('scroll', function() {
    // do your things
    console.log($window.scrollY);

    // or pass this to the scope
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.pixelsScrolled = $window.scrollY;
    })
});
```

I think best way to manage directives

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {

        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
            if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = true;
                 console.log('Scrolled below header.');
             } else {
                 scope.boolChangeClass = false;
                 console.log('Header is in view.');
             }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```